# Error with ScriptManager

Tags: asp.net

Hi I have the following code:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript (Page, Page.GetType (), Guid.NewGuid () ToString (), "document.getElementById ('divwarning') innerHTML = 'my_message';", True);
```

When I write the same method in a class of specific routines (my_tools.cs), the method does not work:

```
public static void showerro (Page pag, string error) 
{
     ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript (pag, pag.GetType (), Guid.NewGuid () ToString (), "document.getElementById ('divwarning') innerHTML =. '" + Error + "';"., True); 
}
```

What is the reason for not working when inside a class instead of calling directly on the page?

Comment: first call this script on document.ready second i found dot(.) missing between innerHTML and  document.getElementById.

Comment: yes its a good idea to ensure the script block is run after dom loading completed . else use it in onbodyload. Sain Pradeep is right in saying an extra dot that causes the issue

Comment: I put the dot in code but isn't working :(